# Find the value in an array one by one

Tags: php, arrays, ip

We would like to know, how can we check the value in array one bye one ... Let me explain you.

want to check the C class ip's into an array, is there any easy function to check the whole thing..

Thanks 
Rod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I do not understand your question.
If you are asking whether an IP adress is in the 192.168.0.0/16 range:

```
$ip = ip2long("192.168.5.7");
$mask = ip2long("192.168.0.0");
if(($ip & $mask) == $mask) 
  echo "Is in 192.168.0.0/16";
else
  echo "Not in range";
```

Comment: cool code. my hunch is that he's looking for array_map or something like that.